# My ... has or have?

Tags: have

I am stuck for several hours now because I don't know if I need to use has or have in the phrases below...

> My first article has been published
>
> My first article have been published

And

> My dream has become a reality
>
> My dream have become a reality

Can someone also explain why I should use has or have in this case...?

Comment: It's very strange that all 3 answers below, which were correct, were downvoted. I upvoted each of them to bring their scores back to 0.

Comment: @CreatedByBrett It was likely an example of "drive-by voting," where somebody didn't like the question so they downvoted all of the answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case the first sentence is correct, because the noun is in the singular:

> My first article has been published
>
> My dream has become a reality

The second of each is correct when the noun is in the plural:

> My first articles have been published
>
> My dreams have become reality

Answer (score 2):

***My first article has been published.*** is correct. The verb *has* must follow a singular noun phrase which is *My first article* in this case. Same is the case for ***My dream has become a reality.*** which is correct. Other two are not correct, and could be corrected as follow;

> My first **articles** have been published.
>
> My **dreams** have become a reality.

The verb *have* must follow a plural noun phrase.

Answer (score 2):

The verb (has/have) applies to the subject. In this case, "My" is not the subject, but instead "My first article" or "My dream". Both of those are singular, so you would use "has".

> My first article *has* been published.
>   My first article**s** *have* been published.
>   My dream *has* become a reality.
>   My dream**s** *have* become reality.